# How do I maintain structure in structured output?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, columns

I am trying to ensure output from a Linux command - which looks like:

[image]

Into a LaTeX document with the same column structure with the output headers lined up with the output sections on the next line. I am using the listings plugin to display the output currently.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash , caption=Viewing a running container]
    $ sudo docker ps
    ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS              NAMES
    80430f8d0921        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/sh -c while tru   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes       red_fox
\end{lstlisting}
```

My actual output ends up looking like:

[image: actual output]

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the question

Comment: Apologies - I thought I did but I've made it clearer.

Comment: Try adding `basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\tiny`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a fixed width font:

[image]

### Notes:

- Also your listing is very wide, even with the `\tiny` applied. Hence, I removed some horizontal spaces in the listing to make it fit horizontally.
- `gobble=4` was used to eliminate the leading horizontal space.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=bash, 
    caption=Viewing a running container, 
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\tiny,
    gobble=4,
    ]
    $ sudo docker ps
    ID            IMAGE         COMMAND                CREATED           STATUS            PORTS       NAMES
    80430f8d0921  ubuntu:12.04  /bin/sh -c while tru   3 minutes ago     Up 3 minutes     red_fox
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```